# Can't build app for iOS devices with Ionic 3

Tags: ios, ionic3, cocoapods, xcode10

I'm developing an app for android and iOS.
I'm using firebase to receive push notifications. When I build for Android, it works fine, but no luck with iOS.
I followed a tutorial for firebase, put the `GoogleService.plist` on resources folder. I've created the authentication key on Apple Developer Website. I have a paid Apple developer account.
I used `cocoapods` to install dependencies of the project.

But, when I run, using the Xcode 10, I got this error:

```
Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/Protobuf.framework/Protobuf(Wrappers.pbobjc.o)
ld: 585 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone have the same issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the following command to build:

Development

```
ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

Production

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

as discussed by the [ionic dev team](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407), the new build system of xcode is not supported yet, then you should use the older one.

When opening the project in Xcode, if you're using a plugin that use cocoa pods as dependence manager, Google Maps is a example, you should open the `ProjectName.xcworkspace` file instead of `ProjectName.xcodeproj` as the **xcworkpace** knows how to compile a cocoa pods plugin dependece based.

Answer (score 0):

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
```

Just as a side note that you will stumble upon, XCODE exposes a Signing bug, so untick the “Automatically manage signing” and tick again in XCODE.